# Django - Use model fields part in a create or update query

Tags: python, django, django-models

Given the following models in a Django 2.2 app:

```
class ShelfPosition(models.Model):
    shelf_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    row = models.IntegerField()
    column = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=["shelf_number", "row", "column"], name="shelfpos_unique")
        ]

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    position = models.OneToOneField(to=ShelfPosition, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, primary_key=True)
```

I rely on Django's lookup feature to filter on `Item` objects depending on some `ShelfPosition` fields:
`Item.objects.filter(position__shelf_code="BF4")`

Is there any way I could implement a similar lookup functionality such as described above when using `get_or_create` or `update_or_create`?

```
item, created = Item.objects.get_or_create(
    position__shelf_code="BF6",
    position__row=88,
    position__column=1,
    defaults={……}
)
```

I find it less verbose than the following, even if with this example it's not really relevant:

```
item, created = Item.objects.get_or_create(
    position = Position.objects.get_or_create(
        shelf_code="BF6",
        row=88,
        column=1
    ),
    defaults={……}
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure this is what you are looking for but if you used [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) you could achieve the following

```py
class ShelfPosition(models.Model):
    shelf_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    row = models.IntegerField()
    column = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("shelf_code", "row", "column")

class Item(ShelfPosition):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

item, created = Item.objects.get_or_create(
    shelf_code="BF6",
    row=88,
    column=1,
    defaults={
       "name": "Spam",
    }
)
```

You'd just have to [make sure to pass `keep_parents=True` when calling `item.delete()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.delete) if you want to preserve the `ShelfPosition` row as the default MTI behavior is to delete the whole ancestor chain.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been trying to achieve, many thanks for your help.
I hope my initial question was clear enough.